# How to remove the last comma of a Wordpress php foreach output?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I already tried some things with trim and so on but nothing works.

Maybe I made a mistake and you can help me? The code looks currently like that:

```
$post = get_post();
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'genre');
if ($terms)
{
    $output = '';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $output .= '<a href="' . get_term_link($term->slug, 'genre') . '">' . $term->name . '</a>, ';
    }
};
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in `substr_replace($term->name,"",-1)`, check [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) for more info, this should delete comma from last string.

Comment: No that delete always the last character of all outputs but not the commas. Maybe because I set the comma after "</a>,"?

Answer (score 0):

just add a counter to check the last item of the array

```
$post = get_post();
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'genre');
if ($terms)
{
    $output = '';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $output .= '<a href="' . get_term_link($term->slug, 'genre') . '">' . $term->name . '</a> ';

      $output .= ($i == count($terms) - 1) ? '' : ',';
      $i++;
    }
};
echo $output;
```

Comment: What does ? and : do, could you please tell me, i was looking for it everywhere but cant seem to find the right explanation

Comment: if the condition is true add the part after `?` else add the part after `:`

Comment: Thx @YazanFouadAldbaisy but that doesnt help. It looks like that now "Animation ,Familie ,Fantasy ,Musical , " (see the last comma after "Musical")

Comment: The code is working fine, check the terms you have, maybe there is one after Musical without a name.

Comment: I checked it – there is no another name :/ It is normal that there is a whitespace after the comma? Like you can see above the output puts first the name and then a whitespace and then a comma. It should "Animation,..." not "Animation ,...".

Comment: To remove the whitespace after the comma just remove it form here  '</a> '; like this  '</a>';

Comment: @YazanFouadAldbaisy Thx for that. But the overall code doesnt work – even if I change the "-1" to "-10" – nothing would be deleted. I dont know why...